# Android: how to write a file locally and save it to the Downloads

Tags: java, android

How do you write files locally and save them to the `Downloads` App in Android?

Android version: `Nougut`

The file is not showing in `Downloads` though. Here's my code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "foo.txt");

try {
    String exampleString = "bar\nfoo";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(data);
    os.write(data);
    is.close();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e.toString());
}

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
        getContext(),
        new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
        null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String s, Uri uri) {
                Log.d(TAG, "String: "+ s);
                Log.d(TAG, "Uri: "+ uri );
            }
        });
```

It is logging this in `onScanCompleted` so it seems like the file should show in `Downloads` but it doesn't.

```
D/SignupFragment: String: /storage/emulated/0/Download/foo.txt
D/SignupFragment: Uri: content://media/external/file/84691
```

I have read the [Android docs on saving files](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "show in `Downloads`"?

Comment: what version of android are you using?

Comment: @CommonsWare I meant to make available in the Android `Downloads` app.

Comment: @yotamhadas I'm using Android N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard AOSP Downloads app only shows what `DownloadManager` downloaded. It does not show files placed in the `Downloads/` directory by other means.

Comment: I just noticed that `DownloadManager` has [`addCompletedDownload()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#addCompletedDownload(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20boolean)), which appears to be a manual way to add items into the Downloads app that you downloaded yourself. This seems like the sort of thing that will be abused eventually (and, then, removed in response), but in the short term, it may be an option for you.